# How can i display a widget after an amount of time even if I leave the screen or close the the app

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:e_sante/variables.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Cures extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<Cures> createState() => _CuresState();
}

class _CuresState extends State<Cures> {
  bool visible=false;
  File ?image;
  Future pickimage() async{
    try{
      final image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if(image==null) return;
      final imageTemp = File(image.path);
      setState(() {
        this.image = imageTemp;
      });
    }on PlatformException catch(e){
      print('failed to pick image:$e');

    }

  }
  Future pickimagecam() async{
    try{
      final image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if(image==null) return;
      final imageTemp = File(image.path);
      setState(() {
        this.image = imageTemp;
      });
    }on PlatformException catch(e){
      print('failed to pick image:$e');

    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double WidthScreen=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double HeightScreen=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[900],
        title: Text(
          'Cure',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
          child: Padding(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 25),
            child: Container(

            ),
          ),

        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: HeightScreen/20),
              child: Text(
                'Confirmer si vous avez passer votre cure',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: HeightScreen/15),
                  shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black,)
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: WidthScreen/30),
                        child: Text(
                          'Oui',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10,),
                      Radio<String>(
                        value: 'Oui',
                        groupValue: cure_val,
                        onChanged: (value){
                          setState(() {
                            cure_val=value!;
                          });

                        },
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 30,),
                Card(
                  shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black,)
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: HeightScreen/15),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: WidthScreen/30),
                        child: Text(
                          'Non',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),

                        ),
                      ),
                      Radio<String>(
                        value: 'Non',
                        groupValue: cure_val,
                        onChanged: (value){
                          setState(() {
                            cure_val=value!;
                          });

                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40,),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  if(cure_val=='Oui'){
                    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5),(){
                      setState(() {
                        visible= !visible;
                      });

                    });
                    
                }else {
                   setState(() {
                     visible = false;
                   });
                  }
            },
                child: Text(
                  'Confirmer',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30,),

      Visibility(
        visible:visible ,
        child:  Column(
          children: [
            Card(
              shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black,),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Insérer votre bilan",
                        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        icon: IconButton(
                          icon:Icon(
                            Icons.camera_alt,
                            size: 18,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(context: context,
                                builder: (context)=>AlertDialog(
                                  actions: [
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            TextButton(
                                              child: Text(
                                                'Prendre une photo',
                                                style:TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18,
                                                ),
                                              ),

                                              onPressed: () {
                                                pickimagecam();
                                              } ,
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(width: 20,),
                                            Icon(
                                                Icons.camera_alt,
                                                size: 30,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            TextButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                pickimage();
                                              },
                                              child: Text(
                                                'Telecharger une photo',
                                                style:TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18,
                                                ) ,
                                              ),

                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(width: 20,),
                                            Icon(
                                                Icons.upload_rounded,
                                                size: 30,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],

                                ),
                              barrierDismissible: true,
                            );
                          },

                        ),

                    ),
                  ),
      image !=null ?Image.file(image!):Text("Aucne image n'a été selectionné")
                ],
              ),



            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                child: Text(
                  'Envoyer',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
            )
          ],
        ),

      )
          ],

        ),
      ),
      

    );
  }
}
```

I want to display a textfield input after an amount of time but the problem is if I leave the screen or I close the app the countdown stop counting the time and the app generate an error . it works only if I stay in the same screen.
[if I choose the option "Oui" and press the button a textfield input appears after an amount of time but if I press the button and leave the screen or close the app the countdown stop counting the time and generate an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiB8V.png)

[Error generated after I leave the screen before the time finishes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z10qi.png)

Comment: You could better use local notifications for it

Comment: @AnkitKumarMaurya how can a local notification help me ?? or you wanna say local storage??

Comment: You can basically start a timer to show a notification for the user if the user has leave the app and if he presses on the notification maybe he will be send to the required screen. For reference to show notification after some time you could check it https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications